# Did Trump just confess to a crime?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, us-president

[This article](https://www.vanityfair.com/news/2022/11/donald-trump-ron-desantis-truth-social-meltdown) quotes trump as saying

> I also fixed his campaign, which had completely fallen apart. I was all in for Ron, and he beat Gillum, but after the Race, when votes were being stolen by the corrupt Election process in Broward County, and Ron was going down ten thousand votes a day, along with now-Senator Rick Scott, I sent in the FBI and the U.S. Attorneys, and the ballot theft immediately ended, just prior to them running out of the votes necessary to win. I stopped his Election from being stolen.

The article says

> To be clear, that was Trump apparently suggesting that he “sent in the FBI” to ensure that DeSantis won, which many have noted warrants an investigation by the people who investigate federal crimes:

Did Trump admit to committing a crime?

Answer (score 5):

If what that quote says is actually *true*, **no** that is obviously **not** a crime. Sending law enforcement to stop a crime is not a crime, no matter who benefits. In fact turning a blind eye and letting someone benefit would have been the crime.

But this is not a legal matter. People are upset because the person saying this has a track record of saying things that are actually *not true* and that is why many people suspect a crime. Because if any part of this sentence turns out to be not true (and based on this persons history, that chance is *very* high), then yes, a crime may have been committed.

If any predecessor had said "I sent the FBI to stop child kidnapping and it stopped immediately", nobody would question that that is obviously not a crime. They would applaud him for it. Because with any predecessor, people would have believed their words to be true, at least in the very broad sense.